# python3 returns unsupported operand when bit shifting an element in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, hex, bit-shift

I have a list of hex values and I need to shift eacgh element by 9 and combine the result with another list.  I have provided an example below of what I tried.

```
x = [hex(10), hex(11)]
y = x[0] << 1
```

This results in an error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for <<: 'str' and 'int'

While the below code works as I like but returns an int

```
x = [0xa, 0xb]
y = x[0] << 1
```

My question is how can I get the first code example to work?

I understand that the list is returning a string and not an int.  I tried to type cast from a str to a hex, but this caused an error.  I then tried to type cast from the string to int to hex and received an error for the str to int type cast.

I need to result to be stored as a hex in the list so changing the list to integers would not work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert hex strings to integers using

```
    int(hex(10), base=16)
```

but that would just return 10.

If you have a list of integers, I would first shift them the amount you need to shift them by, and then convert them to hexadecimal strings using `hex`. The value of a hex and its integers are the same, e.g. `0xa == 10` is `True`. But `hex(10)` returns a string.

So

```
    nums = [10, 11, ...]
    nums = [x << 9 for x in nums]
    hex_nums = map(hex, nums)
```

or something similar.

Comment: I am still new to python so I did not think to the for inside a list.  I took your advice and did the work before the type cast.  Thank your for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use the constructor 'int' with basis 16 to convert the hex values to integers, then use the bitwise operators

```
    a=hex(10)
    b=hex(11)
    x = [int(a,16),int(b,16)]
    y = x[0] << 1

    print(x)
    print(y)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will have to try this in the future.  I was not aware of this.